# How to convert datatype in SPARK SQL to specific datatype but RDD result to a specifical class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am reading a csv file and need to create a RDDSchema
I read the file by using the sqlContext.csvFile

```
val testfile = sqlContext.csvFile("file")
testfile.registerTempTable(testtable)
```

I wanted to change the pick some of the fields and return an RDD type of those fields 
For example : class Test(ID: String, order_date: Date, Name: String, value: Double)

Using sqlContext.sql("Select col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM ...)

```
 val testfile = sqlContext.sql("Select col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM testtable).collect
testfile.getClass
Class[_ <: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] = class [Lorg.apache.spark.sql.Row;
```

So I wanted to change col1 to double, col2 to a date , and column3 to string? 
Is there a way to do this in the sqlContext.sql or I have to run a map function to the result and then turn it back to RDD..
I tried to do the do the item in one statement and I got this error:

```
 val old_rdd : RDD[Test] = sqlContext.sql("SELECT col, col2, col3,col4  FROM testtable").collect.map(t => (t(0) : String ,dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(1)),t(2) : String, t(3) : Double))
```

The issue I am having is the assignment does not result on RDD[Test] where Test is a class defined

The error is saying that the map command is coming out as an Array Class and not an RDD Class

```
 found   : Array[edu.model.Test]
 [error]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[edu.model.Test]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a case class like this:

```
case class Test(
  ID: String, order_date: java.sql.Date, Name: String, value: Double)
```

Since you load your data with `csvFile` with default parameters it doesn't perform any schema inference and your data is stored as plain strings. Lets assume that there are no other fields:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(
  ("ORD1", "2016-01-02", "foo", "2.23") ::
  ("ORD2", "2016-07-03", "bar", "9.99") :: Nil
).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
```

Your attempt to use map is wrong for more than one reason:

- function you use annotates individual values with incorrect types. Not only `Row.apply` is of type `Int => Any` but also your data table contains shouldn't contain any `Double` values
- since you `collect` (which doesn't makes sense here) you fetch all data to the driver and result is local `Array` not `RDD`
- finally, if all previous issues were resolved, `(String, Date, String, Double)` is clearly not a `Test`

One way to handle this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val casted = df.select(
  $"col1".alias("ID"),
  $"col2".cast("date").alias("order_date"),
  $"col3".alias("name"),
  $"col4".cast("double").alias("value")
)

val tests: RDD[Test] = casted.map {
  case Row(id: String, date: java.sql.Date, name: String, value: Double) =>
    Test(id, date, name, value)
}
```

You can also try to use new `Dataset` API but it is far from stable:

```
casted.as[Test].rdd
```